# Add missing comma to a CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV which I process using powershell where occasionally one or more of the rows will be missing one of the comma delimiters. It will always have 3 columns and the 2nd column is optional.

Ex.

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
SomeCol1Val,,SomeCol3Val
AnotherCol1Val,AnotherCol3Val
```

In the above example I need to add another comma to Row #2

I've been able to determine which row needs to be updated and how change the value, but I'm not sure how overwrite that specific row in the file.

```
$csvFile = Get-Content "C:\MyFile.csv"

foreach($row in $csvFile) {

$cnt = ($row.ToCharArray() -eq ',').count
if ($cnt -eq 1) {
    $row = $row -replace ",",",,"
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You’ve updated it with your $row setting line. Now just output $CSV back to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) points out, all that is missing from your code is to write the updated `$row` values back to your input file, using the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Content) cmdlet.

However, I suggest a different, faster approach, using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` option and a single [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operation based on a regex.

```
$csvFile = 'C:\MyFile.csv'

$newContent = 
  switch -File $csvFile {
    default { $_ -replace '^([^,]+),([^,]+)$', '$1,,$2' }
  }

Set-Content $csvFile -Value $newContent -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note that you may have to use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify the desired character encoding, which in Windows PowerShell is the active ANSI code page and in PowerShell [Core] v6+ BOM-less UTF-8.

---

If you wanted to stick with your original approach:

```
$csvFile = 'C:\MyFile.csv'

$newContent = 
  foreach ($row in Get-Content $csvFile) {
    if (($row.ToCharArray() -eq ',').Count -eq 1) {
      $row -replace ',', ',,'
    } else {
      $row
    }
  }

Set-Content $csvFile -Value $newContent -WhatIf
```

---

Note that both approaches collect all (modified) lines in memory as a whole, so as to speed up the operation and also to allow writing back to the input file.

However, it is possible to *stream* the output, to a different file - i.e. to write the output file *line by line* - by enclosing the `switch` statement in `& { ... }` and piping that to `Set-Content`. With your `Get-Content` approach you'd have to use
`Get-Content ... | ForEach-Object { ... } | Set-Content` instead.